# Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.10

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using eclipse neon for first time and I don't know much about it.
I am getting this error in POM

```
Execution generate-classpath-file of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:build-classpath failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.10 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:build-classpath:generate-classpath-file:validate)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-classpath-file of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:build-classpath failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.10 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.10 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(EclipsePluginDependenciesResolver.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:400)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:372)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:102)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.10 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:202)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.2.1 from http://ibiza:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.2.1 from/to nexus (http://ibiza:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): ibiza
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.2.1 from http://ibiza:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.2.1 from/to nexus (http://ibiza:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): ibiza
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Eclipse Neon is 5 years and 15 releases old, why are you using such an ancient release? Try the current Eclipse 2021-09

Comment: First the error message `Failure to transfer...was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval ` looks like a wrong dependency. Furthermore you are using extrem old plugin version....

Comment: Oh...didn't read that... Eclipse Neon... please upgrade asap...Also Maven/JDK/Plugins etc...

Comment: only that version supports my companies product and I am using .3 version

Comment: @PallaviNer In which way does only this retro version support your companies product and why do you not just fix that? Eclipse supports older Java versions and the development of applications based on older Eclipse version.

Comment: The core error seems to be `Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.2.1 from/to nexus (http://ibiza:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): ibiza` - it can't find a very old version of maven-plugin-api

Answer (score 0):

Try checking, from which maven repository server your maven is trying to download that package from.

It seems to be available on Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api/2.2.1/jar

You can try copying the package to your ~/.m2/repository folder under the matching group path and see if that fixes your problem as a workaround.